# Повторить код нужное количество раз раз

Tags: python

У меня есть код, который позволяет мне на имеющихся данных посчитать суммарный балл для 7 случайно вытащенныхх групп столбцов, а также посчитать по этим случайным столбцам статистический критерий Альфа-кронбаха.
В целом код рабочий и не вызывает проблем (хотя, подозреваю, что что-то можно было бы написать и получше и оптимальнее)

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[i.split("_")[0] for i in df.columns], [i.split("_")[1] for i in df.columns]])
df1 = df[random.sample(df.columns.levels[0].tolist(), 7)]
def CronbachAlpha(data):
    Dispersii = data.var(ddof=1)  # дисперсии по каждому i пункту
    Summa_dispersi = Dispersii.sum() # сумма дисперсий всех пунктов
    Summa_po_shcale = data.sum(axis=1) # суммарный балл респондентов по шкалам
    Dispersia_summi = Summa_po_shcale.var(ddof=1) # дисперсия суммарного балла
    nitems = len(data.columns) # количество пунктов
    CronbachAlpha = nitems / (nitems-1.) * (1 - Summa_dispersi / Dispersia_summi)
    return CronbachAlpha

alfa = ['{:.2f}'.format(CronbachAlpha(df1))]
df1["Общий"] = df1.sum(axis = 1, skipna = True)
df1["Общий"]
data = pd.concat([df1["Общий"], ball], axis=1)
data_alfa = pd.DataFrame(alfa)
data_alfa
alfa1 = pd.concat([data_alfa, alpha])
wb = x.Book('Баллы 7.xlsx')
wb.sheets['Балл'].range('A1').options(index=False, header=True).value = data
wb.sheets['Альфа'].range('A1').options(index=False, header=True).value = alfa1
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

При работе с этим кодом я провожу множественные итерации, поэтому после каждой из них мне важно сохранять подсчитанный суммарный балл и альфу. Это как раз отражено в последних 12 строках кода: там я пытаюсь на разные страницы экселя в столбик сохранять подсчитанные значения.
Это все работает, когда я перезапускаю код вручную.

**НО** этот код мне нужно прокрутить 100, а то и 200 раз. Вручную это неудобно. Когда пытаюсь делать бексоонечным циклом While True,  у меня перестают сохраняться мои значения.
Помогите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так и как можно сделать лучше?

Данные со значениями здесь https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pDyDtWI-KW2OlNUEcXLsV7BVooYl9czaB8Ov6q6ApM4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: 'у меня перестают сохраняться мои значения' — а точно перестают, или постоянно перезаписываются в клетку `A1` ? А если пробовать `for k in range(1, 201): "весь код"` и `['Балл'].range('A' + str(k))` ?

Comment: Да, Вы правы, верное замечание, перезаписывает. Сейчас попробую!